# How do I add a label to a d3-generated convex hull?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, polygon

I used d3 v4 and [this technique](http://bl.ocks.org/donaldh/2920551) (slightly modified) to draw a convex hull around nodes in a force-directed graph. Works great, but now I want to label these groups of nodes. Ultimately, I'd like to draw something that looks like [this SVG](http://udbms.cs.helsinki.fi/assets/ubench/model.svg). Is it possible to add a text element to a convex null polygon, so that it would move around as the polygon was moved, or would I need to create a separate grouping of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach the problem like so:

- Create a convex hull polygon from the points
- Find the centroid of that polygon using d3.geom or d3.polygon (depending on version)
- Update some text with that new coordinate at it's center

In d3 v4, this looks something like:

```
var polygon = d3.polygonHull(vertices);
```

Then you find the centroid:

```
var centroid = d3.polygonCentroid(polygon);
```

And update the text:

```
text.attr("transform","translate("+ centroid +")")
```

---

In d3v3 and v2 the code might look more like:

```
var polygon = d3.geom.polygon(d3.geom.hull(vertices));
var centroid = polygon.centroid();
text.attr("transform","translate("+centroid+")");
```

---

As for updating multiple texts at once, there's a bunch of potential methods to accomplish this, so I won't speak to it here.

Here's an example of a [single text](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/6e32f4cc9210ce3b9fb0a728238ae367) element being updated in v4.